# Android studio with Java calling C# ASP.net web api

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, android-studio

Hi guys  I need assistance with calling an asp.net web  API in android studio by implementing post and  get method,  i have  tried to search on the internet and i couldn't find a solution that works for me. Thank you

Comment: Why does the fact that the api is written in c# matter? REST requests don't depend on the language

Comment: Would implementing get and post from Android Studio be sufficient? Why or why not?

Comment: Ori Cohen I only included that just to show where I'm sending requests.

Comment: @vasmos I just want to know how the connection is established and how we send and receive data